# Connecting to "CrewSense" API using ColdFusion, given cURL example

Tags: rest, curl, coldfusion

I am trying to connect to the "CrewSense" API (https://developer.crewsense.com/#introduction) from a ColdFusion intranet.  According to the documentation, the first thing I need to do is request an access token using the CFHTTP equivalent of the following cURL example.

```
curl -v https://api.crewsense.com/oauth/access_token \
-d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" \
-d "client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

So I tried the following CFHTTP request

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.crewsense.com/oauth/access_token" result="qResult" resolveurl="no" method="post">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="client_id" value="YOUR_CLIENT_ID">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="client_secret" value="YOUR_SECRET_KEY">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="grant_type" value="client_credentials">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#qresult#">
```

According to the documentation, if the request is successful and the credentials are correct, I should receive a JSON response like this in the CFDUMP:

```
{
"access_token": "DZs3IeaMP5uEAc2I19kJYl8Tbvsmgq9GaPQPaMjN",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires": 1426274440,
"expires_in": 86400
}
```

But instead, I am getting the following error....

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong, if anything?  Or is this error on their side?

Comment: According to the error message detail the hostname you requested does not match that of the SSL certificate, so the connection is refused. In your code example you are calling `api.crewsense.com` but the error detail says it will only accept `crewsense.com` or `www.crewsense.com`. Try your request again to one of those domains.

Comment: When I navigate to https://api.crewsense.com/ in my browser it works fine. Viewing the certificate shows that it is indeed assigned to `api.crewsense.com`. Can you verify that the request from your ColdFusion server is reaching the correct site? Does the ColdFusion server have an incorrect HOSTS entry or something? Try navigating to https://api.crewsense.com/ from the browser on your ColdFusion server and see if that works or you get the same error.

Comment: The initial issue mentioned above was a ColdFusion update issue.  Once I update CF, this particular error disappeared.  Now I am getting a different error.  Grrr.

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion needed to be updated.  Once I updated the server, this error disappeared.  Thanks everybody for your help.